# Polymorphic relation use cases with Laravel - Design Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design, polymorphic-associations

I try to design my database and I get confuse.

In my app, an user belong to a group and this group may have multiple stocks of only one type of equipement.

Those stocks can be of two types:

- Stock of power lines
- Stock of windturbine

Each stock has an identifier representing the area.
Each stock has multiple equipements.

So, to summarize :

User A belongs to group A.
Group A has :

- Windturbine1 which has 5 individual windturbines
- Windturbines2 which has 10 individual windturbines

User B belongs to group B.
Group B has :

- power_lines1 which has 10 individual powerlines

I tried to represent this scheme like this :

[image]

However, I'm not totally convinced. I'm not sure if the stock table need to be polymorphic with windturbine_area and power_line_area.

[image]

Any insights on this please ?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some `SELECTs` for each case.

Comment: I see some pairs of tables with identical columns; are there more columns?  If not, then it is _probably_ a poor schema design.